# Trouble in retrieving data from SQLite database(Android Studio)

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I am not able to retrieve data from following **code**::

The APP is getting strucked at Fetching Block. The application is running **upto** Fetch Block but when it enters the **Fetch** Block its not responding and **emulator** is not responding after pressing "***Submit***" Button.

```
public void submitButtonClicked(View view) {


    eventName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventName);
    eventDate= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventDate);
    sumbitButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    System.out.println("Taken data!");
    String ename= eventName.getText().toString();
    String edate= eventDate.getText().toString();
    String dbString;
    dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    dbAdapter.open();

    try {
        dbAdapter.createEvent(ename, edate);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MembersActivity.this, "Some problem occurred",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    System.out.println("Written data to table!");
    setContentView(R.layout.event);
    System.out.println("With event file!");

    //Fetch Block starts here
    try {
        dbString = dbAdapter.databaseToString();
        System.out.println("Fetched data!");
        myText.setText(dbString);
        myText.setText(" ");

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem in Fetching data!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The function databaseToString is in **below** ::

```
//Print out the database as a string
public String databaseToString() {
    String dbString="";
    mDbHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String query="select * from events where 1";

    //Cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("eventname"))!= null){
            dbString+=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("eventname"));
            //dbString+=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("eventdate"));

            dbString+="\n";

        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

Comment: Please, remove `where 1` from your query. **NOW**. Also, you should `move your cursor to the next record`, at every step in the cycle.

Comment: tried but still its not working..!

Comment: And how to move cursor at every cycle!

Comment: No i am not getting any error..!

Comment: Also, this is **evil**: `dbString+="\n";`. You should use a StringBuilder, instead.

Comment: I am getting these errors after trying "c.moveToNext()"

Comment: 14 10:00:15.289    1600-1600/? I/System.out﹕ With event file!
06-14 10:00:15.291    1600-1600/? I/System.out﹕ Fetched data!
06-14 10:00:15.292    1600-1600/? I/System.out﹕ Problem in Fetching data!
06-14 10:00:15.292    1600-1600/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Sorry about above comment..Check error now!

Comment: 14 10:00:15.292    1600-1600/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Where is `myText` declared? It seems it's never declared: `NullPointerException`. You are doing something very dangerous here: `setContentView(R.layout.event);`. If `myText` is a TextView which belongs to `R.layout.event`, where do you declare and assign the `myText` object variable?

Comment: Now everything is working...But i cannot see result in myText!!